# Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is in expression '{!request}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page newrequest:

Tags: apex, visualforce

### This is my vf page

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title='NewBookRequest'>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            bookid='{!books.id}'
            <apex:outputText label='BookName :' value='{!books.Name}'/><br/>
            <apex:inputfield value='{!newReq.Requested_From__c}'/><br/>
            <apex:inputfield value='{!newReq.Requested_Till__c}'/><br/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
               <apex:commandButton value='Request' action='{!request}'/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

### This is My controller:

```
public class NewRequestController {
public string currentBookid{get;set;}
public Book_Request__c newReq{get;set;}
public Book__c books{get;set;}
public NewRequestController(){
currentBookid=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Bookid');
    books=[Select id,Name from Book__c Where id=:currentBookid];
        }
public void request(){
   newReq.BookName__c=books.id;
    insert newReq;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Any variable or properties you want to use must be initialized:

```
public class NewRequestController {

    public Book_Request__c newReq{get;set;}

    public NewRequestController(){
        currentBookid=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Bookid');
        books=[Select id,Name from Book__c Where id=:currentBookid];

        // initialize the property
        newReq = new Book_Request__c();
    }
}
```

Apart from this, your code would give an exception when there is no record with Id passed on `currentBookid`.

Comment: Thanks Raul it's working